Can you run an selfie camera video feed alongside the rear-camera using ARKit when I don't need ARKit working for the selfie camera?
The most relevant stackoverflow post from several years ago is the following where they attempt to use ARKit for  multiple cameras, but in my situation, I do need ARKit functionality in the selfie camera feed: ARKit and AVCamera simultaneously
I'd like to know if it's possible to run ARKit alongside another camera session, using the front-facing camera. I'm also interested if there is a low-level solution that bypasses some of the predefined functionality of ARKit to make this work, but still gives me a similar functionality of using ARKit in the rear-facing camera while running a video feed with the front-facing camera. I do not need the front-facing camera to have ARKit functionality, I just want a picture-in-picture of a regular front-facing/selfie video feed while an ARKit session is running in the rear-camera feed. It's essentially simultaneous capture as seen in Apple's sample code here, except they don't implement an ARSession with it: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/capture_setup/avmulticampip_capturing_from_multiple_cameras
The viewcontroller.swift script I have below "works", but it seems like there may be a resource conflict because the front-facing camera will begin its feed, but then it freezes once the rear-facing camera using ARKit begins its feed; so I'm essentially stuck with an image for the front-facing camera.(See image below)
What I've tried (I got the same results with both of these methods/See image below):

Originally I tried the AVCaptureMulticam session with only the front/selfie camera because ARView (back camera view) from ARKit has it's own AVCapture it automatically runs
I tried putting both the ARView and the UIView (front/selfie camera) into a AVCaptureMultiCamSession


import SwiftUI
import RealityKit
import UIKit
import ARKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController : UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet var arView: ARView!
    @IBOutlet var frontCameraView: UIView! //small PiP view
    
    //Capture Session for front camera
    var captureSession: AVCaptureMultiCamSession?
    var rearCameraLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?
    var frontCameraLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer?
    
    override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        //set up ar session for the rear camera already handled by arview
        //start plane detection from ARKit data
        startPlaneDetection()
        
        //set up gesture recognizer for placing 3D objects
        //2d point
        
        arView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap(recognizer:))))
        
        // set up the front camerra for PiP
        setupFrontCamera()
        
        
        
    }
    func setupARSession()
    {
        let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
        configuration.planeDetection = [.horizontal]
        configuration.environmentTexturing = .automatic
        arView.session.run(configuration)
    }
    
    //setting up both rear & selfie camera as a multicamera session
    func setupDualCameraSession() {
        captureSession = AVCaptureMultiCamSession()

        // Rear camera (main AR view)
        guard let rearCamera = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInWideAngleCamera, for: .video, position: .back),
              let rearInput = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: rearCamera),
              captureSession?.canAddInput(rearInput) == true else {
            return
        }
        
        captureSession?.addInput(rearInput)
        
        let rearOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
        if captureSession?.canAddOutput(rearOutput) == true {
            captureSession?.addOutput(rearOutput)
        }

        // Add rear camera preview to arView (ensure it does not interfere with ARKit)
        rearCameraLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession!)
        rearCameraLayer?.frame = arView.bounds
        rearCameraLayer?.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
        arView.layer.insertSublayer(rearCameraLayer!, at: 0)  // Rear camera under AR content

        // Front camera (PiP view)
        guard let frontCamera = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInWideAngleCamera, for: .video, position: .front),
              let frontInput = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: frontCamera),
              captureSession?.canAddInput(frontInput) == true else {
            return
        }

        captureSession?.addInput(frontInput)

        let frontOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
        if captureSession?.canAddOutput(frontOutput) == true {
            captureSession?.addOutput(frontOutput)
        }

        // Add front camera preview to frontCameraView (PiP)
        frontCameraLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession!)
        frontCameraLayer?.frame = frontCameraView.bounds
        frontCameraLayer?.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
        frontCameraView.layer.addSublayer(frontCameraLayer!)

        // Start the session
        captureSession?.startRunning()
    }

    
    
    
    func setupFrontCamera(){
        
        captureSession = AVCaptureMultiCamSession()
        
        // Front camera (PiP view)
        guard let frontCamera = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInWideAngleCamera, for: .video, position: .front),
              let frontInput = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: frontCamera),
              captureSession?.canAddInput(frontInput) == true else {
            return
        }
        
        captureSession?.addInput(frontInput)
        
        let frontOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
        if captureSession?.canAddOutput(frontOutput) == true {
            captureSession?.addOutput(frontOutput)
        }
        // Add front camera preview to the small UIView (PiP view)
        frontCameraLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession!)
        frontCameraLayer?.frame = frontCameraView.bounds
        frontCameraLayer?.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
        frontCameraView.layer.addSublayer(frontCameraLayer!)
        
        // Start the session
        captureSession?.startRunning()
        
        
    }
    

    
    
    
    func createSphere() -> ModelEntity
    {
        //Mesh; why do we want these as immuatables?
        let sphere = MeshResource.generateSphere(radius: 0.5)
        //Assign material
        let sphereMaterial = SimpleMaterial(color: .blue, roughness: 0, isMetallic: true)
        //Model Entity; what's the diff w entity and mesh + material
        //in the context of Swift and how it handles these?
        //Model Entity
        let sphereEntity = ModelEntity(mesh: sphere, materials: [sphereMaterial])
        
        return sphereEntity
    }
    
    
    @objc
    func handleTap(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer)
    {
        //Touch location, on screen
        let tapLocation = recognizer.location(in: arView)
        
        
        //Raycast (2D -> 3D)
        let results = arView.raycast(from:  tapLocation, allowing: .estimatedPlane, alignment: .horizontal)
        //I am assuming the results return a few possible results, so first selects the first
        //returned value (Verify)
        if let firstResult = results.first {
            
            //3D point (x,y,z)
            let worldPos = simd_make_float3(firstResult.worldTransform.columns.3)
            
            //Create sphere
            let sphere = createSphere()
            
            //place sphere
            
            placeObject(object: sphere, at: worldPos)
            
        }
        
    }
    func placeObject(object:ModelEntity, at location: SIMD3<Float>)
    {
        //Anchor
        let objectAnchor = AnchorEntity(world: location)
        
        // Tie model to anchor
        objectAnchor.addChild(object)
        
        // Add Anchor to scene
        arView.scene.addAnchor(objectAnchor)
    }
    func startPlaneDetection(){
        
        arView.automaticallyConfigureSession = true
        
        let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
        configuration.planeDetection = [.horizontal]
        configuration.environmentTexturing = .automatic
        
        arView.session.run(configuration)
    }
}
    

Additionally, when running the application on XCode, I get the following warnings:
    Could not locate file 'default-binaryarchive.metallib' in bundle.
Registering library (/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/CoreRE.framework/default.metallib) that already exists in shader manager. Library will be overwritten.
Could not resolve material name 'engine:BuiltinRenderGraphResources/AR/suFeatheringCreateMergedOcclusionMask.rematerial' in bundle at

I also get the following lines appearing in my console
<<<< FigCaptureSourceRemote >>>> Fig assert: "err == 0 " at bail (FigCaptureSourceRemote.m:275) - (err=-12784)
<<<< FigCaptureSourceRemote >>>> Fig assert: "err == 0 " at bail (FigCaptureSourceRemote.m:511) - (err=-12784)
<<<< FigCaptureSourceRemote >>>> Fig assert: "err == 0 " at bail (FigCaptureSourceRemote.m:275) - (err=-12784)

